# ultrafilter and $KC$-minimal space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

> By definition in a $KC$ space every compact set is closed.
>
> A space $(X,‎\tau)‎‎‎$ is $KC$-*minimal* if $(X,‎\tau )‎‎‎$ is a $KC$ space and there is no $KC$ space $(X,\sigma)$ such that $\sigma\subsetneqq\tau$.
>
> In the  proof of the lemma below I have questions:
>
> **Lemma:Let $(X,‎\tau)‎‎‎$‎ be a $KC$-minimal space, $D$ a discrete subset with non-compact $\tau$-closure, $F$ an ultrafilter such that $D\in F$ and $F$ contains only
>   sets with non-compact $\tau$-closures. Let $\sigma=\{U\in\tau:x_{0}\notin U\}\cup\{U\in\tau:x_{0}\in U\text{ and }U\in\mathcal{F}\}$ .Then every $\sigma$-compact subset is also $\tau$-compact.**
>
> **Proof:** Suppose for contradiction that $M$ is a $\sigma$-compact set which is not $\tau$-compact. Then there is $\tau$-open neighbourhood $U_0$ of $\{x‎_0\}$ such that $M‎ \setminus ‎U‎_0$‎ is not $\tau$-compact either. Let $N=(M\setminus U_0)\cup\{x_0\}$. Now we’ll prove that $N$ is $\tau$-closed. Let $x‎‎\in‎‎‎‎\overline{N}‎$.
>
> Let $x \in V$ be such that ‎$K‎ =‎ ‎‎\overline{V\setminus U‎_{0}‎‎}‎‎$‎ is $\tau$-compact. Then the topologies $\tau$ and $\sigma$ agree on $K$. Since $V$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, we have ‎$x‎\in‎‎\overline{V\cap N}‎\subseteq\overline{K\cap N‎}\cup\{x‎_0\}‎‎‎‎$‎. Note that $N\cap K$ is $\sigma$-compact because it is a closed subset of a compact space $N$. But $\sigma$ and $\tau$ still agree on $K$, hence $N\cap K$ is $\tau$-compact, and so $\tau$-closed. This gives $x\in N$. Finally we have two possibilities:
>
> (a) If $X\setminus N‎\in\mathcal{F}‎‎$ then the topologies $\tau$ and $\sigma$ agree on $N$, and hence it is $\tau$-compact.
>
> (b) On the other hand, if $N‎ ‎\in\mathcal{F}‎‎‎$, then let $D‎' =  D‎\cap ‎N‎$. Since $D‎'$ is discrete, we know that  $\overline{D‎'}‎‎\setminus ‎D‎'$ is closed. Let  $W$ be such an open set, that $\overline{D‎'\cap W} = D‎'$. Then $W‎\cup ‎U‎_0$ is a $\sigma$-open neighbourhood of $x‎_0$.
>
> Now suppose that $\overline{D‎'}$ is not $\tau$-compact (otherwise $N$ would be $\tau$-compact). We know that there is a set $C$ without any complete $\tau$-accumulation
>   points. But $C$ has a complete accumulation point in the topology $\sigma$, hence this point is $ x‎_0$. Then ‎$|(‎ W‎ ‎‎\cup ‎U‎_{0} )‎ ‎‎\cap C‎| =‎ ‎‎|C‎|$, beacuse $W‎\cup ‎U‎_0$ is a $\sigma$-open neighbourhood of $x‎_0$. Since ‎$(‎W‎\cup ‎U‎_0)‎\cap C‎\subseteq ‎D‎'$‎, we can suppose without loss of generality that $C‎\subseteq D‎'$.
>
> Let $D‎_0\cup D_1=‎ ‎C‎$, where $D‎_0$ and ‎$D‎_1$‎ ‎are disjoint and have the same cardinality as $C$. At most one of these sets can be in $F$. Without loss of generality assume that $D‎_1\notin\mathcal{F}‎‎$. Since $D$ is discrete, we get $\overline{‎(D‎_1‎)_\tau‎}\notin\mathcal{F}‎‎$ and so $D‎_1$‎ has no $\sigma$-accumulation points that are not $\tau$-accumulation points. Hence $‎D‎_1$ has no complete $\tau$-accumulation point. This contradicts $N$ is $\tau$-compact.
>
> **so, my problems are**:
>
> 1. why in part (a) we can say: If **$X\setminus N‎\in\mathcal{F}‎‎$ then the topologies $\tau$ and $\sigma$ agree on $N$**, and hence it is $\tau$-compact.
> 2. why in part (b) we can say: $‎‎\overline{D‎'}‎‎\setminus ‎D‎'$ is **closed** and $W‎\cup ‎U‎_0$ is a **$\sigma$-open neighborhood** of $x‎_0$ and (**otherwise $N$ would be $\tau$-compact**)?
> 3. why we can say: $C$ has a complete accumulation point in the topology $\sigma$, hence **this point is $x‎_0$?**

Answer (score 0):

1. The preceding paragraph shows that $N$ is $\tau$-closed, so $X\setminus N\in\tau$. Let $U\in\tau$ be arbitrary, and let $W_U=U\cup(X\setminus N)$; clearly $W_U\in\tau$. If $x_0\notin W_U$, then automatically $W_U\in\sigma$. But $W_U\supseteq X\setminus N\in\mathscr{F}$, so $W_U\in\mathscr{F}$, and therefore $W_U\in\sigma$ is $x_0\in W_U$ as well. Finally, $$U\cap N=\Big(U\cup(X\setminus N)\Big)\cap N=W_U\cap N\;,$$ so for each $U\in\tau$ there is a $W_U\in\sigma$ such that $U\cap N=W_U\cap N$, and hence $\tau$ and $\sigma$ agree on $N$.
2. In (b) the $\tau$-open set $W$ should be chosen so that $\overline{D'}\cap W=D'$. $W$ and $U_0$ are both $\tau$-open, and $x_0\in U_0$, so $W\cup U_0$ is a $\tau$-open nbhd of $x_0$. Finally, $W\supseteq D'=D\cap N$; $D,N\in\mathscr{F}$, so $D'\in\mathscr{F}$, and therefore $W\in\mathscr{F}$; thus, $W\in\sigma$ by definition.
3. The only point of $X$ at which the topologies $\sigma$ and $\tau$ differ is $x_0$, so if $C$ has a complete accumulation point in $\sigma$ but not in $\tau$, that point can only be $x_0$: at every other point $x\in X$ there is a family $\mathscr{B}(x)$ of $\sigma$-open nbhds of $x$ such that every $\tau$-open nbhd of $x$ contains some member of $\mathscr{B}(x)$, and hence $x$ is a complete accumulation point of $C$ in $\sigma$ iff it is a complete accumulation point of $C$ in $\tau$.